# Асихронное выполнение функции

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, socket.io

На сайте после создания заказа клиент переходит на страницу, где ему откликаются боты через рандомные промежутки времени(чтобы выполнить его заказ) . Боты пушатся в socket через php, nodejs принимает и рендерит на странице.

Боты должны переодично пушить сообщения в чат, делать это асинхронно, поскольку боты из сервера могут приходить в рандомном промежутке времени.

**Код на nodejs**

```
managementNsp.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('addBid', function (data) {
     if (data.writer.isBot) {

        function asyncPushToChat() {
             var messagesArray = ["Hello", "Test message"];
             messagesArray.forEach(function(item) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    push(item);
                }, randomSeconds);
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Как функцию asyncPushToChat сделать асинхронной??

если так переписать на промисы, это верно?

```
managementNsp.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('addBid', function (data) {
    if (data.writer.isBot) {
        function asyncPushMessageToChat()
        {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
            {
                connection.query("SELECT text FROM bot_message", function (err, messagesArray) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }

                    messagesArray.forEach(function(item) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            return resolve(item);
                        }, randomSeconds);
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        asyncPushMessageToChat()
            .then(function(res)
            {
                //append to html
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: _asyncPushToChat_ и так асинхронная, за счет использования setTimeout, она просто нигде не вызывалась

Comment: _если так переписать на промисы, это верно?_ - нет. потому что для одного Promise идет попытка выполнить функцию resolve несколько раз

Comment: вместо forEach в промисе - массив промисов, затем Promise.all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал так

```
if (data.writer.isBot == 1) {

        connection.query("SELECT text FROM bot_message WHERE bot_id = ?", data.writer.id, function (err, rows) {

            if (err) reject(err);

            for (var i in rows) {
                var messageData = {
                    from : data.writer.id,
                    orderId : data.bidding.orderId,
                    isPing : data.order.isPing,
                    to : data.bidding.userId,
                    bidding : data.bidding.id,
                    message : rows[i].text
                };

                (function(i, messageData) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        clientSocket.emit('emulateSendMessage', messageData);
                    }, 6000 * i);
                })(i, messageData);
            }

        });
    }
```